# Solutions to $\sum{a_n} = \prod{(a_n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

$$\sum_n^\infty{a_n} = \prod_n^\infty{(a_n+1)}$$

Can you give a nontrivial example of a real sequence which satisfies this equation? By "trivial" I mean sequences such as $-1,1,0,0,0\dots$ which result in the series and infinite product both being zero.

Comment: $a_n = 1$ for all $n$ (or anything resulting in both sides being $+\infty$) should probably also be regarded as trivial.

Comment: If you expand the right side, you get $1 + \sum a_n+\sum\ldots$ where the continuation has the sums over all squares, cubes, and so on. Maybe this helps you continue. Somehow it seems you have infinite terms to set... and only one condition. Should be possible.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I would say so.

Comment: @orion I noticed this, but have no idea of how to manipulate this continuation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rewrite:
$$a_1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n=(a_1+1)\prod_{n=2}^\infty (a_n+1)$$
Just set
$$a_1=\frac{\prod_{n=2}^\infty (a_n+1)-\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n}{1-\prod_{n=2}^\infty (a_n+1)}$$

This means you have an immensely infinite number of solutions. Almost any sequence for which the product exists is ok, if you just prefix it with a first term that satisfies the above condition.

The sequence $\{a_1,1,0,0,0,\ldots\}$ is just one example, but any other is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{x(-1)^n}{n^2}\right) - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x(-1)^n}{n^2}$$

then $f$ is continious with $f(0) = 1$ and $f(-3) < - 1$. By the intermediate value theorem there exist a $x\in(-3,0)$ s.t. $f(x) =0$. Numerically we find $x\approx −2.02467$.